# Assigning two shortcuts for the same action

Tags: shortcut, customization

I'd like to assign two shortcuts to the undo action in blender 2.8 (ctr+z and middle mouse click) but I failed as it seems only one at time is possible. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Please consider using the latest Long-Term-Support stable version of blender i.e., 2.83.1 (which will be supported for 2 years, without major feature change).

Answer (score 1):

## There is a way, but it's a very bad idea

You should not do it. Middle click is used too much to practically change it and retain important functionality in Blender's keymaps.

You would have to add a new entry here in the Preferences(<kbd>F4</kbd> -> <kbd>P</kbd>), Keymap tab, under Screen, Screen(Global):

[image]

But you would also have to search for and remove all the conflicts:

[image]

That would break stuff.
**This would be a very bad idea.**